# Deploy tomcat application to root in openshift

Tags: openshift

I deployed my application in openshift in tomcat container and I noticed that my app is hosted on http:///app-name/ and I want to use http:///

How can I do that in openshift application ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your war file to ROOT.war, then it will be available at http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/, otherwise it will be deployed at `http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/<name of war file>`