# Renamed my .war file to ROOT.war but still has to type full name + /appname

Tags: java, openshift

I read here [Deploy tomcat application to root in openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977205/deploy-tomcat-application-to-root-in-openshift) that by renaming your .war file to ROOT.war, you will be able to do access your website by typing this: http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/ . So I renamed it to root.war but still no changes. I still have to type http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/name-of-war-file

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
`<web-app version="3.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 metadata-complete="false">

<display-name>Advanced Mappings Demo Application</display-name>

<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf</include-prelude>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
<cookie-config>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
</cookie-config>
<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

And this is my onStartUp method (I configured it programmatically):

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException
{
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
servletContext.register(WebServletContextConfiguration.class); 
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
        "springDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(servletContext)
);
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/");
container.getServletRegistration("default").addMapping("/resources/*",   "*.css", "*.js", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.jpg");

}
```

This is the log of my application when being deployed:

[Openshift logs after restarting my application via Eclipse](http://pastebin.com/5jydhNFC)

Comment: Did you named it `ROOT.war` or `root.war` (case sensitive; you're mentioning both variants in your question)? Were there any deployment errors?

Comment: @JiriFiala Thanks for looking into my question. I named it ROOT.war. There were not any deployment errors. None. I have pasted the log messages in my original post. I restarted my application to look if there are any deployment errors.

Comment: @JiriFiala My problem is solved! Check the answer xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay now I got it. Although renaming *.war to ROOT.war was important, I was missing  .jsp file at aN important location. I added "index.jsp" at the root of my web application and inside it I have

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<c:redirect url="/main" />
```

The main thing that's needed here is the 2nd line. It will redirect all the calls headed for http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/ to http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/main, which I actually need. I just type http://demo-farazdurrani.rhcloud.com/ and it redirects it to http://demo-farazdurrani.rhcloud.com/main

First line is optional (not needed for my solution) and is doing this: It is a needed page that doesn't need to be involved in a session. Or if this code is specified in a JSP page, it means session objects will not be available for that page. Hence session cannot be maintained for that page. (just putting it out there not necessary for my question though).

I will show you how my project structure looks like now:

[image: Eclipse Project Director Structure]

Earlier in the question I was asking if I need to change anything in web.xml. No I don't. Everything is fine there.